# iAds not showing as far as I can see - but iAds Network on iTunesConnect showing stats

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

Bear with me, because I haven't figured out what is going on right now.

Situation : My app got approved and published on AppStore approximately 5 days ago. Since that day I have been tracking my app, but I haven't seen any iAds showing on my 2 devices, although my test iAds was working.

1- I have enabled iAd, it is still enabled.

2- I have all contracts on iTunesConnect "in effect".

3- I am checking up on my iAd Network page within iTunesConnect and I can see small impressions, e-CPM and revenue. (which should mean that someone can see iAds somewhere)

Any ideas on what is going on and how should I solve this issue will be appriciated.

Additional information can be supplied.

**Edit:** There are question like this one on StackOverFlow but non of them seem to identify the problem and solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all who is having such issues; (guess I should have been looking deeply before I implement)

According to iAd Developer Support Team;

"iAd advertisements are currently being served to apps on the U.S., U.K., Germany, Italy, Spain, France, Japan, and Canada App Stores. For more information and updates on international expansion"

If your app's primary target counrty is not listed above, you might want to look at https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/ on how to integrate Google Ads on your app.